# jquery ajax success not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I am trying to collect the response of a controller using ajax but I can not I have this code:

```
$.ajax({url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        alert("hi"); //no work.
  }
 });
```

and return it to the controller that:

```
return new Response($venta->getId());
```

the call at controller succefully return number de venta id.
But success does not come into the section.

Comment: You dont only need to return it, but to actually print it. The page you request has to display the id to be able to get it by jQuery Ajax.

Comment: return  new Response(json_encode($array), 200, array('Content-Type', 'text/json'));  only work a numer not json ???

Answer (score 0):

ajax jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: 'json',
    url:url,
   success: function(data) {
     alert("hi");
     }
});
```

return url :

```
$array['id'] = $venta->getId();
return  new Response(json_encode($array), 200, array('Content-Type', 'text/json'));
```

display in browser

```
{"id":89}
```

no show alert (hi) why ? thanks.

Comment: You should not add additional information about your question as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
      <script 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"  
         type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    url='./responsetest.php';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'json',
       url:url,
       success: function(data) {
         alert("hi");
       },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="display"></div>
</body>
    </html>
```

PHP file: responsetest.php

```
    <?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $msg = array('id' => 89);
    echo $_GET['callback'].json_encode($msg);
    ?>
```